# How to update metadata in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to update metadata in mongoDB(Nodejs).

```
 gfs.collection('uploads').updateOne({ filename:image}, {$set: 
 {metadata.likes:1}}, 
 function(err, res) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("1 document updated");


 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code will work if you add `metadata.likes` in brackets like

```js
gfs.collection('uploads').updateOne({ filename:image}, {$set: 
 {'metadata.likes':1}}, 
 function(err, res) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("1 document updated");
 });
```

In this case `"metadata.likes"` would be equal to `1`. Every time it will update it and set it to 1. If you want to increment `"metadata.likes"` by 1, so try this

```js
gfs.collection('uploads').updateOne({ filename:image}, {$inc:
  {'metadata.likes':1}}, 
  function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document updated");
});
```

Comment: Thank You So Much ! but if likes starts from 0 ! then what would i change this code ?

Comment: If `'metadata.likes'` field is 0 number, you can increment it by 1 with the second code. Every time when the code is executed, `"metadata.likes"` will be increased by 1. So the field will be equal to 1, 2, 3 and so on. If you want to decrement the `'metadata.likes'` field you should change `{'metadata.likes':1}` to {'metadata.likes':-1}. In that case, when you execute it multiple times the field would be 3, 2, 1, 0, -1 and so on.

Comment: How to display alert box in nodejs